# Jump Menu values from Database

Tags: php

I want to add a Jump menu, in which values will come from Database, and upon selecting the value from menu, its sub-values should display below with checkbox to editing. Unfortunately I am unable to do it, as in my code, I cant understand whats the problem.
Want to add that I am new to programming PHP.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
function MM_jumpMenu(targ,selObj,restore){ //v3.0
eval(targ+".location='"+selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value+"'");
 if (restore) selObj.selectedIndex=0;
}
//-->
</script>


<?php
$site_query = mysqli_query($Connect, "select * from site order by site_name") or die ("Could Not Get Site Names. Check Query");
$show_site = mysqli_fetch_array($site_query);
?>
<select name="site" class="head_sub" onChange="MM_jumpMenu('parent',this,0)">
<option value="?site_id=0" selected>Select Site.....</option>
<?php
while($get_names = mysqli_fetch_array($site_query))
{
$site_id=$get_names['site_id'];
echo "<option value='?site_id=$show_site[site_id]'"; if($site_id == $show_site['site_id']) echo "selected"; echo ">$show_site[site_name]";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want if is not give more information what you want
try this

```
<select name="site" class="head_sub" onChange="MM_jumpMenu('parent',this,0)">
<?php if(!empty($show_site)){
 foreach($show_site as $sites){ ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $site['id'] ?>" selected><?php echo $site['name'] ?></option>

<?php } } ?>
```

Comment: After putting this code, I am getting below mentioned error.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '[' in D:\wamp64\xxx\xxx\edit_location.php on line 102

Please guide.

Comment: I just want is that "Menu options are displayed from Database" and when any value in menu is selected, then its relevant values are displayed below with checkboxes.
I hope you have understood my point.

Comment: You mean select menu has multiple selected option is it right?    and see your code you were checking same variable  in if  your $show_site and $get_names is same data and i edited my answer I left $ after as in foreach